# How to implement retry (talking to view controller) button in a custom UIVIEW Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview

Hi I am currently developing a simple game by using one view controller.

GAMESPEC

-When playing the game the user can gain scores
-when the game ends the game over screen comes out 
- Game over screens display the score and has a retry button which restarts the game.

Note:
- I am not using spritekit just pure IOS sdk with swift.
- I have one view controller that implements the game
- The game over screen is implemented as a custom UIVIEW

Question

- How can I Implement the retry button in the custom UIVIEW where pressing the button cause

  1. removing the gameover uiview from the screen.
  2. restarts the game logic

Additional Question
- How can I animate the gameoverscreen view so it disappear and reappear smoothly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. in your ViewController you need to have a method to remove your uiview.  Then you'd just do

   `self.gameoverView.removeFromSuperview()`

In order to have access to your UIView in two different methods you need to make it a property of the ViewController class.

2. in your ViewController you can present your scene again to restart the game.  example:

   `self.view!.presentScene(scene, transition: SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1))`

Additional Question:

I'm not going to make a smooth animation for you because ultimately thats going to be your own creative process.  but animating a UIView is pretty easy.  I'll drop some test code you can play with.  if you put this in your ViewController you'll be able to see a red UIView animate.  Using this code you should be able to figure out how to make your own cool animation

```
let testView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)))
testView.backgroundColor = SKColor.redColor()
UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {
    testView.frame.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
})

self.view.addSubview(testView)
```

Comment: Hi thanks a lot, I will try it  and it see how it goes